# Nginx: How to customize page displaying "No Application Found"

Tags: nginx

I tried to edit config ("error_page 500" option). But it looks that it does not work. "No Application Found" page is not the same as 500.html specified in nginx config.

How can I change this information to custom page? Or make redirect? Or at least deny request?

P.S. Nginx uses fastcgi mono server. But I am not sure that it can be related.

[image]

Comment: It happens when I am trying to access this server by another domain pointing to the same server. Obviously cannot find it, but how to avoid such messages...

Comment: It's better to show nginx config. And does this page really return 500 error?

Comment: Browser says 500 status code (Net panel in firebug). Config is default for nginx except specified application in site-available. It contains server section only with listen and location root /var/www/domain.name/;
                 index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
                 fastcgi_index /;
                 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                 include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

Comment: I guess, you need `fastcgi_intercept_errors on` directive

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried it already. In location section (where fastcgi parameters for mono server) and in root of nginx config. Still not working... I restarted nginx and tried all possible combinations. It looks like something hardcoded in nginx (in case of missed application configuration). But I have idea... Maybe it is possible to create default settings to handle all urls (except with mono app).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it as described above in comments. I have created default application using the following settings:

```
server {
    listen       80 default;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  custom.html;
    }
}
```

In this case server responds to all requests using this default configuration with custom html page specified (except of course correct domain which has real application configured).

So this solution does not allow to customize "No Application" page. It allows to respond to browser as necessary (before nginx attempt to find wrong application). This 500 error is not error of my correctly configured application, it is error of nginx.

Any further handling of http errors is also now possible inside this default configuration.